# package.json script to install global module if missing and then use it

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I want an npm script that will:

- Check to see if a global module is installed
- If not, install it
- Use it

There will be a scripts entry in my package.json to do this.

```
"scripts": {
    "exeglobal": "TODO: check to see if global package is installed, if not install it, then use it"
}
```

Anyone know an OS independent way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you list the module as a `devDependency` and then use it? :)

Comment: Good thinking, I tried that but kept getting an error :(

Comment: Could you show us your entire `package.json` file please? And what exact error do you get? Which module do you want to install?

Comment: @Wernerson thanks - your previous comment gave me the answer. If you answer this question then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the module to the `devDependency` and use it like this.